# How to replace first <td> column of a table?

Tags: jquery

I have the following table and would like to replace the string text of each 1st col  with a link .  So, the "Whatever" and "Whatever2" contents would be replaced with an according link .html contents.

How can I do this using jquery?

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Start</th>
       <th>End</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Whatever</td>
       <td>3/14/2012</td>
       <td>3/31/2012</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Whatever2</td>
       <td>3/15/2012</td>
       <td>3/30/2012</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the document is loaded up, you could use something like this:

```
$('td:first-child').each(function(){
  var $td = $(this);
  $td.html('<a href="#">' + $td.text() + '</a>');
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/bVNWf/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('table tr td:first-child').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);

    that.html('<a href="somelink.html">' + that.text() + '</a>');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/eudsv/

```
$('td:first-child, th:first-child').each(function(){
   this.innerHTML += 'Added dynamically'    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("table tr td:first-child").html("<a href='http://google.com'>Click here for Google!</a>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WxzfQ/

Comment: You can't pass HTML into the `text` method; it will be escaped automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this efficiently by passing a [callback to the `html` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

```
$('table tbody tr td:first-child').html(function(i,old) {
    return '<a href="whatever.html">'+old+'</a>';
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wdZbW/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("table tr").each(function(){    
        var existingContent=$(this).find('td:first').text();        
        var newLink="<a href='#'>"+existingContent+"</a>";
        $(this).find('td:first').html(newLink);

   });    

})​
```

Here is the working sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/uH4vW/3/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this is to add an id to the table you want to change and then use a selector in that table for the first `<td>` element

HTML

```
<table id="container">
  ...
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#container td:first').text('found it');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cGYj3/